# Data schema consistency check

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to check the whether collection in database A has the same structure as that of B and C.

For example, collection `xyz` in database A has `id, name and salary` and it has to exactly match with collection `xyz` in databases B and C.

Also please note, I'm trying to achieve this using [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) /JavaScript.

Can someone help me how to start with this?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is schema less but still if you want to achieve what you desire use can use mongodb driver ODM like mongoose to manage the schema and that will help to achieve your desired outcome.

Here is an example in nodejs

#### Schema A

```
const collectionA = mongoose.Schema({
    a: String,
    b: String
});
const colA = mongoose.model('col-a', collectionA);
```

#### Schema B

```
const collectionB = mongoose.Schema({
    a: String,
    b: String
});
const colB = mongoose.model('col-b', collectionB);
```

#### getting all properties defined

```
const propertyOfColA = Object.keys(colA.schema.paths); // [ 'a', 'b', '_id', '__v' ]
const propertyOfColB = Object.keys(colB.schema.paths); // [ 'a', 'b', '_id', '__v' ]

const isCompleteMatched = matchProperties(propertyOfColA, propertyOfColB);
if(isCompleteMatched) console.log("Col-A matched with Col-B");
else console.log("Col-A does not matched with Col-B");
```

#### matching function

```
function matchProperties(colA = [], colB = []) {
    if (colA.length !== colB.length) return false;
    return colA.every(property => colB.includes(property)); // return true if all properties of colA matches with colB;
}
```